# When the crash log produced?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

My Question is that : when and how often our Xcode produce crash logs?

reproduced steps as below:

> 1.Clear the log '~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/' && '~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/' to make sure that all
>   history crash logs were removed from mac

2. Simulate one crash from project [e.g.: insert nil object to dic]
3. Check the path `~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/`

Result: I can't find the crash logs. [i tried device also ,get the same empty crash log]